# how to add quantity increment and decreament (+ and - button) in cart summary magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, knockoutjs

[image]

I want to add increment decrement  functionality in the checkout page how to achieve this

Comment: Do you mean minicat?

Comment: @SukumarGorai its a checkout page  order summary

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Update-Cart-automatically-Using-Increment-and-decrement-Button/td-p/104958

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230281/add-ajax-quantity-increment-and-decrement-button-on-cart-page-in-magento-2

These may be helpful. You did google before posting this right?

Comment: yes, I did @Ankit